# Python: Printing Unique Value in Dictionary along with Count

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on an extension of a logging system. I'm writing a function such that when a user runs the code, we take a look at the run logs, and if there are errors collect them along with the run log itself.

I've been able to do this and have a dict of run logs and the error messages they contain, some errors are duplicated across multiple logs so I'd like to give the user a 'sample' log for each error message, along with the amount of errors that we find.

My dict is something like

```
{
    'run_log_1': 'Syntax error on abc',
    'run_log_3': 'Syntax error on abc',
    'run_log_17': 'Expected int base 10',
    'run_log_23': 'Syntax error on xyz'
}
```

You get the idea.

I'd like to format the output such that the user gets:

```
Error: Syntax error on abc
Total 2, Sample: run_log_3

Error: Expected int base 10
Total 1, Sample: run_log_17
```

How could I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of some of the special collections for this task.

```
import collections

your_log_dict = dict(
      run_log_1='Syntax error on abc',
      run_log_3='Syntax error on abc',
      run_log_17='Expected int base 10')

counts = collections.Counter(your_log_dict.values())

samples = {v:k for k,v in your_log_dict.items()}

for error, count in counts.items():
    sample = samples[error]
    print('Error: {}\nTotal {}, Sample: {}\n'.format(error, count, sample))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked out perfectly. Not sure why my thread has been negatively downloaded but this was great!

Answer (score 0):

You could make an additional dict and put the values of the first dict in it as keys:

```
counts = {}
for sample, error in errordict.items():
   if error not in counts:
      counts[error] = [0, sample]
   counts[error][0] += 1
```

The new dict would then contain the desired counts plus a sample for each count.